# PHP add array to another array auto $key with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array, associative

I'm trying to manage adding one array in another array but that doesn't work. Sorry if the question was already asked (but I can't find it in stackoverflow).

Here is what I'm trying to do :

```
$this->dataSector[0] = array('Secteur' => "S1",
                             'UL'      => intval($this->ulSecteur1),
                             'DL'      => intval($this->dlSecteur1),
                             'details' => [array('MAC' => $this->mac,
                                                 'UL'  => intval($this->ultransrate),
                                                 'DL'  => intval($this->dltransrate)
                                                      )]
                       );
$this->dataSector[1] = array('Secteur' => "S2",
                                 'UL'      => intval($this->ulSecteur1),
                                 'DL'      => intval($this->dlSecteur1),
                                 'details' => [array('MAC' => $this->mac,
                                                     'UL'  => intval($this->ultransrate),
                                                     'DL'  => intval($this->dltransrate)
                                                          )]
                           );
```

Another try :

```
$this->dataSector[0] = array('Secteur' => "S1",
                             'UL'      => intval($this->ulSecteur1),
                             'DL'      => intval($this->dlSecteur1),
                             'details'[] => array('MAC' => $this->mac,
                                                  'UL'  => intval($this->ultransrate),
                                                  'DL'  => intval($this->dltransrate)
                                                      )
                       );
$this->dataSector[1] = array('Secteur' => "S2",
                                 'UL'      => intval($this->ulSecteur1),
                                 'DL'      => intval($this->dlSecteur1),
                                 'details'[] => array('MAC' => $this->mac,
                                                      'UL'  => intval($this->ultransrate),
                                                      'DL'  => intval($this->dltransrate)
                                                          )
                           );
```

Or :

```
$this->dataSector[0] = array('Secteur' => "S1",
                             'UL'      => intval($this->ulSecteur1),
                             'DL'      => intval($this->dlSecteur1)
                       );
$this->dataSector[0]['details'][] = array('MAC' => $this->mac,
                                          'UL'  => intval($this->ultransrate),
                                          'DL'  => intval($this->dltransrate)
                                     );
$this->dataSector[1] = array('Secteur' => "S2",
                                 'UL'      => intval($this->ulSecteur1),
                                 'DL'      => intval($this->dlSecteur1)
                           );
    $this->dataSector[1]['details'][] = array('MAC' => $this->mac,
                                              'UL'  => intval($this->ultransrate),
                                              'DL'  => intval($this->dltransrate)
                                         );
```

**Desired array :**

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Secteur' => string 'S1' (length=2)
      'UL' => int 1
      'DL' => int 0
      'details' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              'MAC' => string 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx' (length=17)
              'UL' => int 1
              'DL' => int 0
          1 => 
            array (size=3)
              'MAC' => string 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx' (length=17)
              'UL' => int 1
              'DL' => int 0
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Secteur' => string 'S2' (length=2)
      'UL' => int 0
      'DL' => int 0
      'details' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              'MAC' => string 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx' (length=17)
              'UL' => int 1
              'DL' => int 0
          1 => 
            array (size=3)
              'MAC' => string 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx' (length=17)
              'UL' => int 1
              'DL' => int 0
```

What's the good solution please ?

Comment: You last try should work. What the issue of the last try？

Comment: @KrisRoofe the issue is always key 0. The key doesn't increment itself :\

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php) :

```
<?php
$this->dataSector[0]['details'] = array_merge($this->dataSector[0]['details'], array(array('MAC' => $this->mac,
      'UL'  => intval($this->ultransrate),
      'DL'  => intval($this->dltransrate)
  )), array(array('MAC' => $this->mac,
      'UL'  => intval($this->ultransrate),
      'DL'  => intval($this->dltransrate)
  ))
);
```

$this->dataSector[1](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php)['details'] = $this->dataSector[0]['details'];

Comment: hi, i edited my question so i don't know if you answer is related with my modifications. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->dataSector[0] = array('Secteur'=>"S1",'UL'=> intval($this->ulSecteur1), 'DL'=> intval($this->dlSecteur1),'details' => []);

$dt=array('MAC' => $this->mac,'UL'=> intval($this->ultransrate),'DL'  => intval($this->dltransrate));

array_push($this->dataSector[0]['details'], $dt);
```

Comment: I tried your code but the key of ['details'] array is always 0. The auto increment is not working.

Comment: Before adding a new detail you must create a array value and add into the principal array
For example:

Comment: For new value you must do this
`$this->mac='Yosemite',$this->ultransrate='xxxxxxx',$this->dltransrate='xxxxxx'
$dt=array('MAC' => $this->mac,'UL'=> intval($this->ultransrate),'DL'  => intval($this->dltransrate));
array_push($this->dataSector[0]['details'], $dt);
// $this->mac='El Captain',$this->ultransrate='xxxxxxx',$this->dltransrate='xxxxxx'
$dt=array('MAC' => $this->mac,'UL'=> intval($this->ultransrate),'DL'  => intval($this->dltransrate));
array_push($this->dataSector[0]['details'], $dt);`